# Is possible return more than one return type in a Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use asp.net 4 and c#.

I would like to know **if could be possible return more than one return type in a Method**.

As example in this method I return only a single bool type.

```
   protected bool IsFilePresent()
    {
            return File.Exists(Server.MapPath("/myFile.txt"));
    }
```

But lets imagine I would like return also a string type using in the same method like:

```
string lineBase = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("/myFile.txt"));
```

Is possible to do it?

I would appreciate some code example. Many Thanks.

Comment: Methods can have only one return type/value. Why would you want to return anything other than a `bool` in a method called `IsSomethingSomething()`?

Comment: Thanks BoltClock, I'm asking just for learning reasons

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not possible to return multiple, different values. You have a few alternatives:

1. One is to make a [`class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b0thckt.aspx) or [`struct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) that has each of the things you want to return as properties or fields.
2. Another is to use [`out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx) parameters, where you pass in a variable to a method, which the method then assigns a value to.
3. You could also use [`ref`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) parameters (pass by reference), which is similar to `out`, but the variable you pass in needs to have been assigned before you call the method (i.e. the method changes the value).

---

In your case, as [cjk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52201/cjk) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253687/is-possible-return-more-than-one-return-type-in-a-method/7253723#7253723), you could just have the method return a string with the file contents, or null to indicate that the file didn't exist.

Comment: Do you think Tuple could be a solution to take in consideration in your answer? Many thanks for your time on this.

Comment: Yes, it could be. The Tuple generic classes are just built in, generic classes. The downside of using that though, is that the properties aren't named specific to your use.

Answer (score 3):

For this example, you have 3 choices.

1. Add an out parameter to your method and set it in the body (code below)
2. Create a custom class that contains a Booelan and a String and return that
3. Just return the string, but return null when the file does not exist

---

```
protected bool IsFilePresent(out String allText) 
{ 
     Boolean fileExists = File.Exists(Server.MapPath("/myFile.txt")); 
     if (fileExists)
     {
         allText = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("/myFile.txt")); 
     }
     return fileExists;
}
```

Comment: Note that `out` parameters are discouraged by Microsoft (coding guidelines CA1021) http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(AVOIDOUTPARAMETERS)&rd=true

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can only if your using framework 4. Look into tuple

http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/tuple-in-c-4-0/

Comment: Without framework 4 it could easily be done, but he'd have to create the class himself.

Comment: I'll add that before 4.0 you could use `KeyValuePair` as a `Tuple` of 2 elements.

Comment: Thanks for pointing our Tuple I did not know about theme. As MSDN says Tuble could be used "To return multiple values from a method without using out parameters (in C#) or ByRef parameters (in Visual Basic)." So could be useful in my case.

Answer (score 0):

No, you could use `out` parameter instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx(v=vs.80).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645764(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can return a class with different types in it :

```
class TestFile
{
    private bool isFilePresent;
    private string lineBase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a wrapper class called (for instance) "Pair" parametrized with two types, put two values in the object of that class and return it as a result. In your case it would be something like Pair

I'm not a C# programmer, so I won't give you exact code.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

First one, more C-ish: out parameters:

```
void test(out bool p1, out bool p2) {
  p1 = true;
  p2 = false;
}
```

Second one, more OO, use a struct or class to contain your results:

```
class Result {
   public bool Part1 {get;set;}
   public bool Part2 {get;set;}
}

Result test() {
   return new Result {Part1 = true, Part2 = false};
}
```

In C# 4 you can use the [Tuple class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) instead of creating your own result class.

I did not look at your specific requirement but you can combine the methods if you need, but keep in mind that the out parameters are discouraged in object oriented programming at least as per microsoft guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `out`-parameters.

```
protected bool IsFilePresent(out string fileContents) {
  string filePath = Server.MapPath("/myFile.txt");
  try {
    fileContents = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    return true;
  } catch {
    fileContents = null;
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use exception handling to direct program flow, this is a bad example.

Comment: Please elaborate why this is bad practice. I can't see any antipattern .

Comment: Becuase creating an exception is VERY expensive and should be avoided at all costs.  Why else would there be methods like `Int32.TryParse` when you could just cast it and catch the exception?

Comment: I see that point, but how does it concern program flow (other than performance)?

Comment: I don't dispute that it works, just that because of the performance issue, it is a bad practice to get into.

Comment: @cjk let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3033/discussion-between-fjdumont-and-cjk)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use output parameters.

```
public bool GetData(string filename, out string data)
{
    if (File.Exists(filename))
    {
        data = File.ReadAllText(filename);
        return true;
    }
    data = string.Empty;
    return false;
}

string data;
if (GetData(Server.MapPath("/myFile.txt"), out data))
{
     // do something with data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can. dotNet 4 support dynamic type, so you can return more than one type

```
    public dynamic GetSomething()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(Server.MapPath("/myFile.txt")))
            return false;
        else
            return File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("/myFile.txt"));
    }

 var result = GetSomething();
 if(result is bool && result == false)
 {
     //doSomething();
 }
```

This way is hard to read your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy nowadays... use Tuple

```
public (string,int) MyMethod(){
   return ("text", 3);
}   

string text;
int number;
(text, number) = MyMethod();

//OR
(var text, var number) = MyMethod();
```